# Performing a get request in Python

Tags: python, parsing, url, get

Please tell me why this similar lists of code get different results.
First one (yandex.ru) get page of request, and another one get Main page of site (moyareklama.ru)

```
import urllib

base = "http://www.moyareklama.ru/single_ad_new.php?"
data = {"id":"201623465"}
url = base + urllib.urlencode(data)
print url
page = urllib.urlopen(url).read()
f = open ("1.html", "w")
f.write(page)
f.close()
print page

##base = "http://yandex.ru/yandsearch?"
##data = (("text","python"),("lr","192"))
##url = base + urllib.urlencode(data)
##print url
##page = urllib.urlopen(url).read()
##f = open ("1.html", "w")
##f.write(page)
##f.close()
##print page
```

Comment: I would guess since they are different sites you get different results ...

Comment: first example return request page, another main page of site

Comment: Make your life easier with the [Requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) module

Comment: I don't understand why in first example url return Main page? but if I copy this url in browser I receive request page.

Answer (score 2):

Most likely the reason you get something different with urllib.urlopen and your browser is because your browser can be redirected with javascript and meta/refresh tags as well as standard HTTP 301/302 responses. I'm pretty sure the urllib module will only be redirected by HTTP 301/302 responses.